# I need to make a VBSEditor program where if i is 1 j must be 9,if i is 2 j must be 8,if i is 3 j must be 7 and so on

Tags: vbscript

I need to make a VBSEditor program where if `i` is 1, `j` must be 9, if `i` is 2, `j` must be 8, if `i` is 3, `j` must be 7 and so on. The set of allowable `i-j` pairs is:

```
1-9, 2-8, 3-7, 4-6, 5-5, 6-4, 7-3, 8-2, 9-1
```

What I have done up until now is this, but I'm having problems like "(2, 9) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement" and other.

```
Int main()
Int N= 2;
Int board(Int array[N][N]);
{
     Int i = 1;
     Int j = 10;
     while(i<10)
     {
         printf(i);
         i++;
    while(j>0)
         printf(j);
         j--;
    }    
}
```

What i need is a formula or a full code that will do this for me.

Comment: Because it is jscript and not vbscript. Call it something.js.

Comment: Help file is here - http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe.

Comment: Wrong language that is JScript / JavaScript not VBScript.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem doesn't fit the language they are trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of the below codes:

```
i = 1
If i >= 1 And i <= 9 Then
    j = 10 - i
Else
    Err.Raise vbObjectError, , "Argument is out of range"
End If
MsgBox j
```

or for arbitrary values:

```
i = 1
Select Case i
    Case 1 j = 9
    Case 2 j = 8
    Case 3 j = 7
    Case 4 j = 6
    Case 5 j = 5
    Case 6 j = 4
    Case 7 j = 3
    Case 8 j = 2
    Case 9 j = 1
    Case Else Err.Raise vbObjectError, , "Argument is out of range"
End Select
MsgBox j
```

or for large number of values packed in the string:

```
Data = "1-9, 2-8, 3-7, 4-6, 5-5, 6-4, 7-3, 8-2, 9-1"
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each Item In Split(Data, ", ")
    Pair = Split(Item, "-")
    Dict(Clng(Pair(0))) = CLng(Pair(1))
Next

i = 1
If Dict.Exists(i) Then
    j = Dict(i)
Else
    Err.Raise vbObjectError, , "Argument is out of range"
End If
MsgBox j
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude all work and thanks for the variety of your answer.

Comment: @sakiszero please click to accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: Ok yeah done thanks i got one more question how can i do this in the vbs console of excel?
IF Q1>=10 THEN Q1 = Q1-10
ELSE PUT Q1 IN O1

Comment: @sakiszero I guess you mean Immediate window in Excel VBA Project Editor? Why do you need to do that immediate, but not as macro? Better you to create another one question and describe the issue, since it will be tagged VBA, also comments are not for extended discussion.